# Unable to capture the id of div clicked

Tags: jquery

This is my jsfiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/6TUtw/4/

How can i register for the event  div click , so that i can get the name

i have tried with different things , but none of them worked .

```
$('#tabs div').click(function() {
    var elem = $(this);
    alert(elem);
    });

$('#tabs').on('click', 'div.click', function () {
   var elem = $(this);
    alert(elem);
});

$("#tabs").click(function(){
   var elem = $(this);
    alert(elem);
});
```

Comment: are you sure about the fiddle? It seems some other url

Comment: `this.id` no need to wrap it in jquery again.

Comment: Please post fiddle with the above code integrated.

Comment: As Amit already said: unclear what you intend to do since the fiddle and your sample don't match. Can you post one sample in the source code so we know where you try to put this code?

Comment: It's not quite clear what you're asking. Are you looking for the tabs `activate` event?

Comment: I mean once we click on the tab , i need to get the name .

Comment: What do you mean by 'so that i can get the **name**?' If you click on One you get 'One'?

Comment: I mean once i clickk on tab One , i will get that name as one .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you want the text(you are refering which as name) for clicked tab. Try this:

```
$("#tabs").tabs();
$("#tabs li a").click(function(){
  alert($(this).text())
});
```

**[Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/6TUtw/1/)**

Comment: Thank you Milind , that is waht i was looking for exactly .

Comment: @urbz: Agreed. I think it's probably because of the "try this" and then lack of explanation about what the "this" is doing. There are a lot of "try this" with no explanation answers that really aren't helpful. This (no pun!) one, though, is close enough. Could use some explanation, but certainly doesn't rate a downvote. Not even close.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder: indeed agreed. Need to change try this approach. this has caused me many downvotes on other answers even though the answer is correct.

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#tabs").click(function(){

    // Get the ID of the clicked tab    
    var the_id = $(this).attr('id');

    // Alert with the ID
    alert (the_id);
});
```

Comment: Why the extra conversion for a simple property? Why not just `this.id`?

Comment: Because `this.id` will return a blank string if there is no ID on the element, but `$(this).attr('id');` will return undefined.

To be fair, `this.id` is quicker and if I'd drank enough coffee then I'd have suggested that; you're right.

Comment: JQuery `$(this).attr('id')` will not return `undefined` if the id is missing. It will return an empty string. Do you mean `this.id` will be undefined (if so, order more coffee) :)

Comment: Odd. I just got some really nice new coffee, and somehow stumbled upon this answer. You were right, btw.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
   $("#tabs").tabs();
    $("#tabs li").click(function(){
      alert($(this).text());
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this. Assuming name - Tab Name . Here is a **[Working Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/shaun1ak/6TUtw/5/)**.

```
$("#tabs").tabs();
$("#tabs li").click(function(){
  alert($(this).attr('aria-controls'));
});
```

or

```
$("#tabs").tabs();
$("#tabs li a").click(function(){
  alert($(this).text());
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$('#tabs ul li').click(function(){
    alert($(this).attr("aria-controls"))
})
```